# How to get the current value of /alertson in Skype?

Tags: skype

I am using the `/alertson [text]` command of skype to only get alerts on some keywords.

Sometimes, I would like to temporarily enable/disable all alerts and later restore the previous `/alertson`. However I don't remember which keywords I'm currently using and I don't want to forget to input one.

Is it thus possible to get the current value?

Comment: It can be useful the skype [help/chat page](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10042/what-are-chat-commands-and-roles)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

If you Right Click on the group chat's "tab", then click Notification Settings... it shows you your current alert keywords, allows you to change them, and adjust some other features.

Additionally, your user information and messages are stored in `%appdata%\skype\[your username]` on Windows and in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/[your username]` on OS X in a file called main.db. It's an SQLite database, so you could potentially programmatically retrieve or change the values if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the 'Conversation' Menu at the Chat Window. There you will find "Notification Settings". You can view and edit all the keywords enabled for this Chat.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.